# Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.QBFC8Lib' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quickbooks, qbfc

I am using a quickbooks sdk that containst the QBFC8Lib dll
everything works fine on my dev machine. 
when I publish to my live server I get the following error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.QBFC8Lib' or one of its
```

`enter code here`dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

I have the sdk installed on both my dev machine and the live machine. still getting this error

Comment: Sounds like a 32bit 64bit thing.  Are the servers a different bit than your dev machine?

Comment: You areexactly right. on the server I went to the application pool for this application and needed to set enable 32 bit applications to true. That did it.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You areexactly right. on the server I went to the application pool for this application and needed to set enable 32 bit applications to true. That did it. Thanks for your help